# How to display context menu on double click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Do we have option in WPF control to show Context Menu on Double Click . I couldnt find DoubleClick event for WPF control.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Specifically which control? Buttons for example certainly have a DoubleClick Event and after that it's as simple as `Button.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;`

Comment: I need it on textblock..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this on the MouseDown Event by evaluating the `MouseButtonEventArgs` for the `ClickCount` property.

For example:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ClickCount >= 2)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        textBlock.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer helped me partially .. I triggered windows mouse event  through this event                       
            if (e.ClickCount == 2)
            {
                var mousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
                int X_axis = (int)mousePosition.X;
                int Y_axis = (int)mousePosition.Y;
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, X_axis, Y_axis, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, X_axis, Y_axis, 0, 0);
            }

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with opening the context menu as per your original question but I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: its just triggered windows right button click event so context menu opens automatically.. :)